# ClamAV Antivirus Linux (Qué archivos están infectados?)

Tags: linux, centos

Tengo un servidor que tuvo un pequeño problema con algún que otro virus, así que le instalé un antivirus, en este caso Clam AV, programé un escaneo nocturno mediante crontab, y con el comando

`clamscan -r --bell -i / > /var/log/clamscan.log`

al consultar el log, veo que pone un resumen y nada más.

Pone `infected files: 9` pero no dice cuales son, como puedo saber que archivos están infectados? que comando debería usar para que me ponga que archivos están infectados?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por defecto, no guardará un listado de los ficheros, solamente el resultado del escaneo, para guardar dichos datos necesitas decirle que los almacene:

```
clamscan -r -i / | grep FOUND >> /var/log/clamscan.log
```

Saludos,